# Python Code to remove punctuation from dictionary not functioning correctly

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I already turned in this assignment but it is driving me crazy. We were given a method to strip punctuation from a dictionary using a "for" loop with this example:

```
import string​
​
quote = " The joy of coding Python should be in seeing short, concise, readable classes that express " \​
        "a lot of action in a small amount of clear code -- not in reams of trivial code that bores the " \​
        "reader to death. "​
​
print(quote)​
word_list = quote.split()​
for word in word_list:​
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation)​
        print(word)
```

Our assignment for the week was to take the Gettysburg address saved as a .txt file and create a dictionary that has a count of how many times all the words appear. My first try I did this:

```
import string


def word_counter(speech, word_dictionary):
    for word in speech:
        if word in word_dictionary:
            word_dictionary[word] += 1
        else:
            word_dictionary[word] = 1

def process_line(word_list, word_dictionary):
    ##split speech into list of words
    words_split = word_list.split()
    ##remove puncation from list
    for word in words_split:
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
    else:
        word_counter(word, word_dictionary)
        # Printing extra Values
        pretty_print(word_dictionary)

def pretty_print(word_dictionary):\
    ##clean up values that shouldn't be there
    ##word_dictionary.pop("")
    ##word_dictionary.pop("19")
    ##word_dictionary.pop("1863")
    ##word_dictionary.pop("Abraham")
    ##word_dictionary.pop("Lincoln")
    ##Calculating how many words are in the dictionary
    word_count_sum = len(word_dictionary.items())
    print("Length of dictionary: ", word_count_sum)
    for key, value in sorted(word_dictionary.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True):
        print("%s: %s" % (key, value))

def main():
    ##creating empty dictionary
    word_count_dict = {}
    ##uploading file
    gba_file = open('gettysburg.txt','r')
    data = gba_file.read()
    process_line(data,word_count_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What happens with this is the only entries in the dictionary are 1,9,8,3. I did a print statement and it is running through the entire loop. It also is looping through the entire list when after the split. I was able to complete the assignment by using:

```
for word in words_split:
    for character in word:
        if character in string.punctuation:
            word = word.replace(character,"")
    input_list.append(word)
```

but I am trying to learn so I want to know what I was doing wrong. Can anyone help? Sorry for the lengthy post and let me know if you need the .txt file to solve this.

Comment: Hint : what happen to the words after strip ?

Comment: The only place in this code that strips punctuation is this line `word = word.strip(string.punctuation)`, which does not do anything to update the dictionary...

Comment: remove `else` in `process_line`

Comment: `word_counter` expects to get a list (or some iterable) of words and iterate over it: that's what `for word in speech` does.  If you give that function a single word, it will instead iterate over its letters. So `word_counter('four', d)` will add 1 to the counts for 'f', 'o', 'u' and 'r' in `d`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an errant `else` in here that's messing up your `for` loop:

```
    for word in words_split:
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
    else:
        word_counter(word, word_dictionary)
```

The `else:` clause executes only once (or never) after the `for` loop is completely done (unless there's a `break`), so you're only calling `word_counter` on the very last `word` from the loop.  You don't need the `else:` here at all; just delete that line, and `word_counter` will be called once per `word`.

Note that Python comes with a built-in class, `collections.Counter`, that will do this exact thing without you having to write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string​
​
quote = " The joy of coding Python should be in seeing short, concise, readable classes that express " \​
        "a lot of action in a small amount of clear code -- not in reams of trivial code that bores the " \​
        "reader to death. "​
​
for s_char in string.punctuation:
    quote = quote.replace(s_char,"")
```

The function .replace() replaces all characters in the string, not only one